# New page after -- conditional formula

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have two groups in my report,

1)When i choose group2 parameter = none then all the groupers in group1 should be on same page.

2)However if I select group2 <> none then all the groupers in group1 should start in a new page.

If I check new page after 2) is working fine where as 1) isn't. I have tried to use the formula {?Group 2} <> "None" in new page after section but its throwing me an error "a number or currency amount is required"

Not sure how to handle this, need some help thanks!!!

Comment: What data is filled in your Group2 field? It seems that it is a number

Comment: what is datatype of ` {?Group 2} `

Comment: Data type of group2 is a number

Answer (score 1):

Since the datatype of your parameter `{?Group2}` is number, then the value `"None"` will never be filled in it.

You have to write this formula in the suppress condition of new page after:

```
IF (IsNull({?Group2})) or ({?Group2} = 0) then 
  true
```

In this case, if the value is null, or 0 it will add a new page after this group.

Answer (score 0):

Its asking for a number to use for number of pages in page break value..

If you put this in the formula it should work.
IF ({?GroupParam}="1")
then 1
else 0